# I am creating a Python program where objects from two different classes have to interact

Tags: python, class, object

Here, an object from Enemy class attacks pic object from antihero class. What I want is the life of pic should decrease consistently as the attacks from en keep piling over. But the life decreases just once.

Also, when I print the life of pic separately to verify, the life of pic doesn't appear to change at all. I have included both the script and the output for more illustration.

```
 class Enemy():
    life = 100

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def attack(self, a): # a here is an object in antihero class.
        a = antihero()
        a.attacked()

class antihero():

    life = 100

    def attacked(self):
        print "I am getting attacked!"
        self.life -= 5
        print "Anti-hero's life: ", self.life

pic = antihero()
en = Enemy('black')

for _ in range(3):
    en.attack(pic)
    print pic.life
```

Output:

```
I am getting attacked!
Anti-hero's life:  95
100
I am getting attacked!
Anti-hero's life:  95
100
I am getting attacked!
Anti-hero's life:  95
100
```

Comment: why you are creating new object everytime using `a = antihero()`? You can directly do `a.attacked()` where `pic = antihero()` is antihero object already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the attack method of `Enemy` class, you are creating fresh instance of `antihero` class every time when the `attack` method is called. When the attack method is called, a fresh object of `antihero` class is created every time and attribute `life` is initially `100` and then it becomes `95` when the `attacked` method of `antihero` class is called.

In non-technical terms it means you are creating multiple antihero's for a single enemy. I guess, according to your intent, the battle is between single antihero and a single enemy .

So, stop creating multiple antiheros by removing `a = antihero()` and keep only  `a.attacked()` in `attack` method, where `a` is already a antihero class object passed as an argument to `attack` method.

```
def attack(self, a): # a here is an object in antihero class.
        a.attacked()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this line a = antihero()`. The method `attack(self, a)` accept an argument. As such you pass an enemy object to it to attack it.
     class Enemy():
        life = 100

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def attack(self, a): # a here is an object in antihero class.
        a.attacked()

class antihero():

    life = 100

    def attacked(self):
        print ("I am getting attacked!")
        self.life -= 5
        print ("Anti-hero's life: ", self.life)

pic = antihero()
en = Enemy('black')

for _ in range(3):
    en.attack(pic)
    print (pic.life)
```